# Java using Graphics in a Method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener, drawimage

Hi guys I'm super new to Java; I've looked around and haven't been able to find an answer to this question. Any chance you could help me?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public class FrameWork extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
... //Irrelevant to the question code
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

int x = e.getX();
int y = e.getY();
if (x==1 && y==1){
// This is where and when I want to draw GFXDice
}
}}
```

Now the other class, all imports left out for readability.

```
public class Board extends JPanel{
Image GFXDice1; 
public Board() {
ImageIcon Dice1;
Dice1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("GFX/Dice1"));
GFXDice1 = Dice1.getImage();
}
```

Now the graphics part

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.drawImage(GFXDice, 100, 100, null);
}
```

Now for the question - I want to use the method paint from the Class Board in the Class FrameWork - But can't get it to work - any ideas ? I'm offering a bazillion units of good karma to anyone who has an idea.

Comment: use paintComponent for JPanel, 1st code line should be super.paintComponent

Comment: Follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general way to do most Swing drawing is via *passive* graphics. This means:

- Do the drawing itself in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of a JPanel or JComponent.
- In your MouseListener change the state of some of the fields of the class. In your `mouseClicked` method you are setting the state of some *local* variables, and I recommend that you instead make your x and y fields, not local.
- Then when the mouse listener is done making changes, call `repaint()` on the JPanel.
- Then in the paintComponent method, **use** those fields that were changed in the mouse listener to do your drawing.
- Don't forget to call the super's paintComponent method in your paintComponent override.
- Don't forget to read tutorials on Swing Graphics to get the fine points.

---

**Edit**

For example, please have a look at a small graphics program that I created for an answer to [another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23346668/522444).

The drawing occurs in the main class, SpaceShip, which extends JPanel. I add an anonymous inner MouseAdapter class for my Mouse Listener, and inside of the MouseAdapter, I call a method called moveIt, passing in the MouseEvent object.

```
   MouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
        moveIt(evt);
        count = count + 1;
     }

     @Override
     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
        moveIt(evt);
     }
  };
  addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
  addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
}
```

All `moveIt(MouseEvent evt)` does is to change the state of two fields, myX and myY, and then calls `repaint()` on the current class:

```
public void moveIt(MouseEvent evt) {
  myY = evt.getY() - sprite.getHeight() / 2;
  myX = evt.getX() - sprite.getWidth() / 2;
  repaint();
}
```

And then in the class's `paintComponent` method, I first call the super's paintComponent to allow it to erase any previous old out of date images, then I paint a background image, background, then I draw a sprite that uses the myX and myY variables to tell it where to draw, then I draw some yellow rectangles at locations that are determined by the JPanel's size:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  font1 = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 36);
  g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
  g.drawImage(sprite, myX, myY, this);
  g.setColor(Color.yellow);
  int rectCount = 10;
  int height = getHeight() / rectCount;
  int width = 272;
  int x = getWidth() - width;
  for (int i = 0; i < rectCount; i++) {
     int y = i * height;
     g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
  }
  g.setFont(font1);
  g.drawString(Integer.toString(count), 500, 100);
}
```

The whole thing looks like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.lang.String;
import java.awt.Font;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SpaceShip extends JPanel {
   private static final String BACKGROUND_PATH = "http://www.thatsreallypossible.com/"
         + "wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Space-Colonialisation.jpg";
   private static final String SPRITE_PATH = "http://www.pd4pic.com/"
         + "images250_/ufo-flying-saucer-spacecraft-spaceship-alien.png";

   private Font font1;
   int myX = 100;
   int myY = 400;
   int count = 0;
   private BufferedImage background;
   private BufferedImage sprite;

   public SpaceShip() throws IOException {
      URL backgroundUrl = new URL(BACKGROUND_PATH);
      URL spriteUrl = new URL(SPRITE_PATH);
      background = ImageIO.read(backgroundUrl);
      sprite = ImageIO.read(spriteUrl);

      MouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            moveIt(evt);
            count = count + 1;
         }

         @Override
         public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
            moveIt(evt);
         }
      };
      addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
      addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (background != null) {
         return new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
      }
      return super.getPreferredSize();
   }

   public void moveIt(MouseEvent evt) {
      myY = evt.getY() - sprite.getHeight() / 2;
      myX = evt.getX() - sprite.getWidth() / 2;
      repaint();
   }


   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      font1 = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 36);
      g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
      g.drawImage(sprite, myX, myY, this);
      g.setColor(Color.yellow);
      int rectCount = 10;
      int height = getHeight() / rectCount;
      int width = 272;
      int x = getWidth() - width;
      for (int i = 0; i < rectCount; i++) {
         int y = i * height;
         g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
      }
      g.setFont(font1);
      g.drawString(Integer.toString(count), 500, 100);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Basic Game");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      SpaceShip ex;
      try {
         ex = new SpaceShip();
         frame.getContentPane().add(ex);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setResizable(false);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         ex.requestFocus();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 you should be put an [answer here too another repaint()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434550/keyboard-not-inputing-anything-java)

Comment: @mKorbel: thanks. I'll let you answer that question. :)

Comment: @mKorbel: OK, I did give that question a stab at an answer.